# getServerSideProps causes 500 error when deployed on vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

When I'm running my code in localhost everything works how I want it, but when I run it on vercel it sends a 500: internal server error.

I've checked my env variables a million times and tried a lot of things but I'm still rather new with this so I feel like I've been running around like a headless chicken.

any help would be appreciated!

**GitHub:** https://github.com/IvanDuran02/slagville

**Website:** https://slagville.vercel.app/

**getServerSideProps in my index.tsx which then passes message prop into a component**

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  try {
    connectMongo(); // connect to db

    const messages = await Message.find(); // fetch messages from database

    return {
      props: {
        messages: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(messages)), // serializing messages or washing turns into string and re parse to JSON
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return {
      notFound: true, // returns 404 if error
    };
  }
};
```

**Error Message that is in Functions section on vercel panel**

[GET] /
14:35:59:67
2022-07-23T18:36:00.835Z    219794d0-7b7b-4ddc-8eb6-207359ce9444    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"MongoParseError: Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"","reason":{"errorType":"MongoParseError","errorMessage":"Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"","stack":["MongoParseError: Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"","    at new ConnectionString (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js:86:19)","    at parseOptions (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/connection_string.js:209:17)","    at new MongoClient (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:62:63)","    at /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:796:16","    at new Promise ()","    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:793:19)","    at /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:379:10","    at /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5","    at new Promise ()","    at promiseOrCallback (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: MongoParseError: Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"","    at process. (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:775:15)","    at process.emit (node:events:539:35)","    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:140:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:274:27)","    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:97:32)"]}
Unknown application error occurred

Comment: Please add relevant code here. Nobody is interested in digging through github repositories seaching for bugs ... `connectMongo` throws an error. Proably you are using an environment variable for you mongo connection string, but that environment variable isn't set correctly for your deployment

Comment: _"MongoParseError: Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://""_ - This indicates the URL for MongoDB is not correct (probably not set). As @derpirscher mentioned, double-check you're setting the environment variables correctly in Vercel, see https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables.